# Any way to monitor discovered BLE peripherals without connecting?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

Is there any way of being notified if a discovered BLE peripheral moves out of range or otherwise drops out of sight? I'm using `rxBleClient.scanBleDevices()` to build a list of devices in the area that are advertising, but before shipping this list to the main application I'd like to be sure that all the devices are still reachable. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: when you scan for device you got rssi value compare that

Comment: But the rssi value is from when the device was discovered. If it then moves out of range, the rssi won't be updated without a new scan, right?

Comment: yes ,you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanilla Android Scan API allows for scanning BLE devices with callback types of:

```
/**
 * A result callback is only triggered for the first advertisement packet received that matches
 * the filter criteria.
 */
public static final int CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH = 2;

/**
 * Receive a callback when advertisements are no longer received from a device that has been
 * previously reported by a first match callback.
 */
public static final int CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST = 4;
```

The same API is available via `RxBleClient.scanBleDevices(ScanSettings, ScanFilter...)`

The `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` and `CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` are flags that can be put into `ScanSettings`.

The timeout after which the `CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` is triggered is somewhere around 10 seconds. This may be an indication that a particular device is no longer in range/available.

Comment: Great info, thanks—but there seems to be a limitation in that `MATCH_LOST` is only reported for devices that were found with a `FIRST_MATCH`. If I'm using `ALL_MATCHES` then I guess this won't work.

Comment: If you are interested in moments when a device appears and disappears then `FIRST_MATCH` and `MATCH_LOST` is useful. If you use `ALL_MATCHES` then you would need to do that filtering by yourself. You may check the [backport implementation of the functionality for API <21](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/internal/scan/ScanSettingsEmulator.java).

Comment: When I try to use `.setMatchMode()` Android Studio can't find it, and I see that code is commented out in your `ScanSettings` source.

Comment: `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`, `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH`, `CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST`, its set by `.setCallbackType()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Transformer` that will collect scanned devices and emit a list, that is kept up to date, depending on how long ago the device was recently seen.

Comment: Currently I `.map()` each `ScanResult` to a new instance of my device class, and if it is not already present in my `List<device>`, I add it. Would removing an earlier instance of the device before adding the new one have the effect you describe? How would I remove devices from the list if they go offline? Appreciate any details you can provide. (Would this be something to consider adding to RxAndroidBle?)

Answer (score 0):

Robert, that may not be exactly what you expect but treat it as an example. My `Transformer` is emitting a list of items whenever it has been changed, either because an update from the scanner or the eviction happened (checked every second).

```
class RollingPairableDeviceReducer(
        private val systemTime: SystemTime,
        private val evictionTimeSeconds: Long,
        private val pairableDeviceFactory: PairableDeviceFactory
) : Observable.Transformer<ScannedDevice, List<PairableDevice>> {
    override fun call(source: Observable<ScannedDevice>): Observable<List<PairableDevice>> {
        val accumulator: MutableSet<PairableDevice> = Collections.synchronizedSet(mutableSetOf())
        return source
                .map { createPairableDevice(it) }
                .map { pairableDevice ->
                    val added = updateOrAddDevice(accumulator, pairableDevice)
                    val removed = removeOldDevices(accumulator)
                    added || removed
                }
                .mergeWith(checkEvictionEverySecond(accumulator))
                .filter { addedOrRemoved -> addedOrRemoved == true }
                .map { accumulator.toList() }
    }

    private fun createPairableDevice(scannedDevice: ScannedDevice)
            = pairableDeviceFactory.create(scannedDevice)

    private fun updateOrAddDevice(accumulator: MutableSet<PairableDevice>, emittedItem: PairableDevice): Boolean {
        val existingPairableDevice = accumulator.find { it.deviceIdentifier.hardwareId == emittedItem.deviceIdentifier.hardwareId }
        return if (existingPairableDevice != null) {
            accumulator.remove(existingPairableDevice)
            existingPairableDevice.updateWith(emittedItem)
            accumulator.add(existingPairableDevice)
            false
        } else {
            accumulator.add(emittedItem)
            true
        }
    }

    private fun checkEvictionEverySecond(collector: MutableSet<PairableDevice>): Observable<Boolean>
            = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map { removeOldDevices(collector) }

    private fun removeOldDevices(accumulator: MutableSet<PairableDevice>): Boolean {
        val currentTimeInMillis = systemTime.currentTimeInMillis()
        val evictionTimeMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(evictionTimeSeconds)
        return accumulator.removeAll { (currentTimeInMillis - it.lastSeenTime) >= evictionTimeMillis }
    }
}
```